# Get a CloseReason when Application.Run() returns?

Tags: .net, winforms

When a form is closed, it gets a useful argument in its `FormClosed` event, `CloseReason`. However our app runs with only a tray icon and no windows open most of the time. When it exits, I'd like to log the reason it exited - in particular, knowing `CloseReason.WindowsShutDown` and `CloseReason.TaskManagerClosing` would be useful.

Is there any way to check for the above after `Application.Run` returns, in the absence of any `Form` instances?

Comment: Hmm... What do you mean by '... the absence of any Form instances'? Do you mean that you want to get this value after the last form is closed? Or do you have a WinForms application that runs without any forms at all?

Comment: Most of the time it runs without any forms at all. The user can open a form, but it gets destroyed once they're done using it.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting application. :-) Why did you use windows forms instead of running it as a service?

Comment: Firstly, what do you mean by "instead of" - surely if it were a service it would still need to use WinForms for when it needs to show some UI. Secondly, what's so unusual about this? Skype has no visible windows most of the time, but it's just a user app, and so doesn't run as a service. There's simply no advantage in that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way of doing this, but you could always do your own.

The easiest would probably be to add a static property to your Program class where you assign the CloseReason you get in the FormClosed event. This could then be read in your code at a later point.

Alternatively you could create your own class that derives from [`ApplicationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext.aspx) and handle the FormClosed event there. That might be a cleaner approach, but it would also be more cumbersome to set up.

Comment: The former idea won't work because there are no forms to be closed. Looking at whether ApplicationContext can do this, thanks for the link.

Comment: ApplicationContext can't do this either. Normally I would -1, but that seems unreasonable since learning about ApplicationContext was still handy...